# MVC Dropdownlist Populating Another Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

Created a form with 2 input fields and 3 cascading Dropdownlists in MVC.

The dropdownlists populate each one fine, my issue is when the dropdownlists pull back only one result, it doesn't allow me to select that one result to populate the next dropdownlist that corresponds.

Jquery Code,

```
  var server = "";
    function populateDropdown(dropdownId, requestPath, requestData, valueFunction, textFunction) {
        var dropDown = $("#" + dropdownId);
        dropDown.val(null);
        dropDown.empty();
        $.getJSON(requestPath, requestData, function (data) {

            if (!data || !data.result)
                return;

            $.each(data.result, function (index, object) {
                dropDown.append($("<option />").val(valueFunction(object)).text(textFunction(object)));
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#serverTextbox").blur(function () {
            var newServer = $.trim($(this).val());
            if (newServer === server)
                return;
            server = newServer;
            populateDropdown('usersCombo', 'LoadUsers', { server: server },
                function (object) { return object; },
                function (object) { return object; });
        });

        $("#usersCombo").change(function () {
            var user = $.trim($(this).val());
            populateDropdown('databaseCombo', 'LoadDatabases', { server: server, user: user },
                function (object) { return object; },
                function (object) { return object; });
        });

        $("#databaseCombo").change(function () {
            var database = $.trim($(this).val());
            populateDropdown('companyCombo', 'LoadCompanies', { server: server, database: database },
                function (object) { return object; },
                function (object) { return object; });
        });
    });
```

Also here is my issue,

[Issue with dropdownlists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDOi8.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is only one result, then `trigger` a `change` after you have appended the option:-

```js
function populateDropdown(dropdownId, requestPath, requestData, valueFunction, textFunction) {
  var dropDown = $("#" + dropdownId);
  dropDown.val(null);
  dropDown.empty();
  $.getJSON(requestPath, requestData, function(data) {

    if (!data || !data.result)
      return;

    $.each(data.result, function(index, object) {
      dropDown.append($("<option />").val(valueFunction(object)).text(textFunction(object)));
    });

    if (data.result.length == 1) {
      dropDown.trigger('change');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using the change event when there is only one option. In order to allow the user to change the value you need to add an alternative, like an empty entry.

However, if you need to display that only option and still populate next dropdown, I see two different options:

- use a click handler (why else would you click on a one entry
  dropdown?)
- immediately populate the next dropdown (after all, that is the only
  option for the user anyway)